# adding a view in queue using django-rq

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am using rq to do queuing in django.while i am adding a view function which returns a template showing loading  in queue it is giving an error but if a normal function which doesnt take request as its input is working fine.. how to do so

```
    def r():
        print "hello"
```

working correctly
but

```
    def page1(request):
         return render(request, 'new1/index.html', {'currentdate': "sdf"})
```

is not working. how to do so.
my main aim is to run hive queries using django. to do so i need to make that python script wait until it has completed querying and show "processing"  at that time.
therefore i used queuing solutions like rq and want to add my script in queue and as it completes redirect it to a different template page

Comment: can you show the error log please?

Comment: How are you calling this? Are you sure you are actually passing the request object?

Comment: TypeError: page1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 479, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 466, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: page1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

11:21:44 Moving job to failed queue.

Comment: what is the use of request over here?

Comment: You can see from the error that you are not giving the function a request object: TypeError: page1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

You are using not passing a request object to this function, hence you get the error. Either update how you are calling it or pass the required object.

You would probably be fine if you update your function to:

```
def page1():
   return render('new1/index.html', {'currentdate': "sdf"})
```

Comment: i have tried but then it gives 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: in that case you could either use another function to render, one that only takes a template and context or mock a request object...

Answer (score 0):

for this, i just need to change the way in which these functions are working. A function which is taking request(i.e., accessed through url by web) cannot be accessed through enqueue.
therefore we need to return these template through other function which is queuing the other task.